# Повышение скорости работы сайта при его расположении в ОЗУ

Tags: php, c++, веб-программирование

Не сказал бы, что мой сайт валится от количества посещений (5 чел/сутки). Но с прицелом на будущее. Намного ли скорость работы сайта повысится, если его расположить в ОЗУ?

Comment: Читая комменты, взвешивая за и против, я всё-таки не смог уклониться от предварительной оптимизиции... Так как мой движок будет работать с несколькими сайтами, то управлять им будет SiteManager (менеджер сайтов). Сайт содержит в себе странички, странички содержат модули... Вот эту структуру я расположу в памяти... А дальше уже пусть модули работают с базой данных...

Comment: Молодец! Похоже Вы хакер (в старом добром смысле этого слова). Мне кажется (почитав комментарии и глянув сайт), что для начала (конечно, уже для продолжения) не помешает почитать что-нибудь о внутренностях ОС и тогда куча подобных вопросов отпадет (появятся более конкретные, их можно будет и пообсуждать). Например, ["Ядро Linux. Описание процесса разработки"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/17925734/) Р. Лава (предыдущие издания можно и сети найти) читали?

Comment: А еще посмотрите в сторону HP The Machine и мемристоры, возможно эта штука изменит парадигмы программирования.

Comment: Разработка ядра линукс и какие-нибудь мемристоры пока не относятся в сферу моих интересов :) Я пишу свою CMS и задавая вчера вопрос, было интересно услышать мнение других программистов. Я его услышал, понял что смысла нет располагать весь или часть сайта в ОЗУ, но удержаться от этого не смог и уже реализовал у себя такой подход: структура сайта (менеджер сайтов , странички, модули) хранятся в оперативной памяти, а дальше уже модули работают с базой

Comment: То, что Вы сейчас делаете -- это понятно.  Но, неужели не хочется немного заглянуть в свое будущее (с шансами оказаться на "гребне волны")? / Какие-то мемристоры это (как обещает HP) **энергонезависимое** (т.е. при выключении питания содержимое сохраняется) компактное ОЗУ терабайтных размеров (даже в смартфоне обещают терабайт поместить). А вот для того, чтобы быть в состоянии оценить влияние таких технологий на интересную вам прикладную область, крайне желательно хорошо знать, как на самом деле работает ядро. / Надеюсь, доступно пояснил?

Comment: По поводу же конкретного вопроса  "размещать все в ОЗУ", могу сказать, что сейчас в энтерпрайзе все больше смотрят на такие решения (скажем, про [SAP HANA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_HANA) что-нибудь слышали?), так что и Вам есть смысл (при достижении определенной глубины своих знаний) развивать свой проект в этом направлении.

Comment: Это всё ОЧЕНЬ ИНТЕРЕСНО! Но пока не моё... Моё сейчас лабать CMS на C++ )

Answer (score 5):

Ранее было совершенно верно замечено, что вам в таком случае придется размещать и бд в оперативной памяти, при этом любой сбой на сервере или обычная перезагрузка уничтожит все данные.  В таком случае вам придется думать о хитроумном кэшировании, когда основная база будет лежать на диске, а в оперативной памяти будет крутиться кэш, который время от времени надо будет синхронизировать с базой на диске. В общем, проблем довольно много.

Я бы добавил к этому еще и то, что это никак не поможет справиться с ограничениями протокола http, с помощью которого передаются данные запросов и ответов, а также с ограничениями по скорости, предоставляемой провайдером. Можно сколько угодно гонять данные на сервере с умопомрачительными скоростями, зависящими от частоты вашей ОЗУ, но если у клиента какие-нибудь 20 мегабит в секунду (а у многих гораздо меньше), то никакая ОЗУ вам не поможет - ваш сайт просто сможет быстрее ничего не делать. 
Как показывает практика, сайты, работающие с большими нагрузками, вполне справляются без подобных извращений.

Кроме того, никогда не забывайте про то, что преждевременная оптимизация - корень всех зол (или как там говорил [тот умный дядька](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82,_%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD)). Пока что у вас целых 6 юзеров в день. Лучше позаботьтесь о том, чтобы их стало хотя бы в 100 раз больше, и чтобы им там было чем заняться.

Answer (score 2):

Как уже написали в других ответах, вы начинаете решать проблему не с того конца. Однако, формальным ответом будет *нет*. Начиная с версии 5.5 PHP поставляется вместе с расширением OPCache, которое кэширует файлы в оперативной памяти, что практически идентично ram-диску, в более ранних версиях это расширение устанавливается через PECL.

Comment: Я не использую PHP.. пишу для скорости на C++

Comment: @sitev_ru тогда что делает эта метка в вопросе? Вдвойне непонятно, откуда этот вопрос, если вы пишете на плюсах. У вас приложение не fcgi-серваком что ли, которому всего один раз загрузиться?

Comment: Добавил метку PHP, чтобы услышать мнение PHP-шников, а метку C++ удалил модератор... Разбирался с FastCGI, но потом пришла идея сделать свой веб-сервер и свою CMS поверх него... Сайт sitev.ru на этом и крутится

Comment: Вы захотели услышать мое мнение, чтобы под ним написать "мне это не нужно"?

Comment: Ну почему же... А разве, если много ОЗУ, файлы автоматом не кешируются в оперативке?

Comment: О да, их туда запихивает волшебный единорог, поставляющийся с каждой материнской платой. Механизмы PHP я описал выше - там, если мерять с точки зрения версий, только-только внедрили опкэш в стандартную поставку. Откуда у вас такие вопросы про сишку - лично мне непонятно, у вас на выходе должен быть один бинарник, который один раз читается в память, и висит там, сколько хочет (ну, может, файлы шаблонов и статика должны остаться снаружи). В этом случае время загрузки файла с диска играет нулевую роль.

Comment: Предполагается, что у CMS будет работать с несколькими файлами... Приходит мне, например, site.ru/page1 ... Я должен в базе сделать выборку: select id siteId from sites where url='site.ru', получив идентификатор сайта, я ищу страничку: select * from pages where siteId='1' and page='page'... Можно объединить эти запросы в один... Но если слепить тоже самое с помощью класса map, будет явно быстрее)

Comment: @sitev_ru из вышесказанного никак не вытекает, что файлов должно быть много и что они должны подгружаться при каждом запросе.

Comment: Я про такое и не пишу...

Comment: Тогда вопрос не имеет смысла

Comment: Предполагается, что будет много сайтов, много посещений, запросов и т.д.. Ну или очень, очень много)))

Answer (score 1):

На грамотно организованных нагруженных сайтах вся база данных хранится как обычно на диске, а в памяти держат наиболее часто используемые данные. Эта вещь называется кэшированием и организуется она обычно с помощью memcached или Redis и многочисленных обёрток к ним.

Типичная схема работы такова: при запросе (к бд от приложения или от пользователя приложению - зависит от того, на каком уровне кэширование организовывать) проверяется наличие требуемых данных в кэше, если есть - возвращаем данные из кэша, если нет - делаем запрос к бд и перед возвращением записываем данные в кэш. При изменении данных кэш чистится. При нехватке памяти кэш может чиститься автоматически.

Но, разумеется, в первую очередь стоит оптимизировать запросы к БД. Ну а без нагрузки заморачиваться этим особого смысла нет.

Answer (score 0):

Одно из наиболее узких мест в быстродействии это база данных. **Предположим** её можно разместить в ОЗУ, тогда при отключении питания сервера все данные в БД потеряются. Этого можно избежать используя энергонезависимую память HDD, SDD.
На начальных этапах проекта вы, скорее всего, не столкнетесь с по настоящему высокими нагрузками и большим объемом данных. Для начала попробуйте оптимизировать количество запросов и сами запросы к БД.

Comment: Самое узкое место всегда одно и совсем не всегда это БД.